# VBA Excel , 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I get the error 91, when I run the macro from another table than "Buffer" ( so the primary table where I want to search). I really searched a lot, but i am not able to find an answer =(

Here is my Code, `r.select` is where the error occurs.

```
Sub Suchen_3()

    Dim Tabelle_1 As String
    Tabelle_1 = "The following table shows the relevant performance indicators"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Buffer")        

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells.Find(Tabelle_1)        

    ws.Select
    ws.Activate

    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1").Activate          

    **r.Select**   > here attemps the error !          

End Sub
```

When I use:

```
Cells.Find(what:="The following table shows the relevant performance indicators", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1)).Select
```

There is no error, also when I start from another table.

I hope you can help me. If u have any questions, i will answer

Greets

Florian

Comment: Yu need to check if the find was successful `if not(r is nothing) then r.select else debug.print "not found" end if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons for getting this error:

1. You need to specify in which sheet you want to use the `Find`. Instead `Set r = Cells.Find(Tabelle_1)` use `Set r = ws.Cells.Find(Tabelle_1)`.
2. You need to trap the scenario in case `Find` was unable to find `Tabelle`, so before `Select`ing it, check if `If Not r Is Nothing Then`.

**Note**: not sure why you need to select this range after you found it, 99% of the times you don't need to `Select`, you can directly modify/copy/delete without `Select`ing first.

***Modified code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Suchen_3()

Dim Tabelle_1 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

Tabelle_1 = "The following table shows the relevant performance indicators"

Set ws = Worksheets("Buffer")

Set r = ws.Cells.Find(what:=Tabelle_1, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

If Not r Is Nothing Then ' make sure Find was able to find the string
    ws.Select
    r.Select
Else
    ' raise an error in case Find failed
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & Tabelle_1 & " in worksheet", vbCritical
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That fast answer :D Thanks a lot, it runs now properly =)